# Apex Trigger on OpportunityLineItem: Attempt to de-reference a null object error

Tags: apex, trigger, after-trigger

I've been trying to figure this error out for a while now and it seems that I just can't figure it out. When adding an **opportunitylineitem** to an **opportunity**, I keep receiving the **error**

> "Attempt to de-reference a null object"

right after the following line in my code

`prod.inventory_forecast__c += (oli.quantity * opps.get(oli.OpportunityId).probability);`

> **Trigger**

```
trigger InventoryForecast on OpportunityLineItem (after update, after insert) {

Product2[] prods;
Product2 prod;

// creates a map of opportunities
Set<ID> oppIds = new Set<ID>();
for(OpportunityLineItem oli : Trigger.new) {oppIds.add(oli.opportunityId);}
Map<ID, Opportunity> opps = new Map<ID, Opportunity>([SELECT Id, Probability FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN :oppIds]);


// creates a map of products
Set<ID> prodIds = new Set<ID>();
for(OpportunityLineItem oli : Trigger.new) {prodIds.add(oli.Product2Id);}
System.debug(prodIds);
Map<ID, Product2> prods2 = new Map<ID, Product2>([SELECT Id, inventory_forecast__c FROM Product2 WHERE Id IN :prodIds]);


OpportunityLineItem oldOLI, newOLI;
Decimal diff;

for(OpportunityLineItem oli : Trigger.New){

    if(Trigger.isInsert){
        // increase forecast by amount * opp probability

        prod = prods2.get(oli.Product2Id);
        System.debug(prod);
        prod.inventory_forecast__c += (oli.quantity * opps.get(oli.OpportunityId).probability);

        prods.add(prod);

    }
    /*
    if(Trigger.isUpdate){
        // increase of decrease forecast by amount
        // compare Trigger.New to Trigger.Old

        // use newMap and oldMap as lists may not have same records and records may not be in same order
        oldOLI = Trigger.oldMap.get(oli.Id);
        newOLI = Trigger.newMap.get(oli.Id);

        if(newOLI.quantity == null) {newOLI.quantity = 0;}
        if(oldOLI.quantity == null) {oldOLI.quantity = 0;}

        diff = (newOLI.quantity - oldOLI.quantity) * opps.get(oli.OpportunityId).probability;


        prod = prods2.get(oli.Product2Id);
        prod.inventory_forecast__c += diff;

        prods.add(prod);

    }
    */
}

update prods;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the value in expression `prod.inventory_forecast__c += (oli.quantity * opps.get(oli.OpportunityId).probability);` is null.Can you try putting a check someting like below and see if the issue persists?

```
If(oli.quantity != null && opps.keyset().contains(oli.OpportunityId) == true && opps.get(oli.OpportunityId).probability != null) {
                    prod.inventory_forecast__c += ( oli.quantity  *  opps.get(oli.OpportunityId).probability );
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You issue is most likely due to `prod.inventory_forecast__c` being null.

Change it to this:

```
if(prod.inventory_forecast__c == null) prod.inventory_forecast__c = 0;

if(oli.quantity == null || opps.get(oli.OpportunityId).probability == null)
    prod.inventory_forecast__c = 0;
else
    prod.inventory_forecast__c += ( (oli.quantity == null ? 0 : oli.quantity) * opps.get(oli.OpportunityId).probability);
```

The first if may be overkill but just in case

Checking the maps may be overkill since an OLI cannot exist without the OpportunityId being populated. As long as you construct the prior code properly the maps should be safe to simply get and dereference

Whenever you dereference

- +=, -=
- .[field]
- [string].startsWith() and other string methods
- etc

You need to ensure that the value being dereferenced is not null